# Is it possible to get all new checkins at specified location?

Tags: windows-phone-7, foursquare

I'm developing a windows phone application based on foursquare API, here is a scenarios like this:　A user is walking on the road with a phone. He uses my application to find out who just check-in (including strange's check-in) in foursquare around his location, is it possible to implement this request? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the foursquare API indicates that there appears to be a way to get just what you're after.
Simply get a list of nearby venues and then find out who is at each:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow

Comment: Check-ins depend on specific venue, not a coordinate.